# Casting Objective-c to CoreFoundation is disallowed. Looking for alternatives

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-foundation

The following code block used to get all identities from login and system keychains.

I prefer working with objective-c types like NSArray for the output list of identities. However, method `SecItemCopyMatching` accepts only CoreFoundation types (CFArrayRef) do I had to cast the NSArray to CFArrayRef when calling it.

```
    CFMutableArrayRef arrayContent = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

    for (const std::string& keychainName : 
         {"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain", "login.keychain"}) {
         status = SecKeychainOpen(keychainName.c_str(), &keychain);
         if (status != errSecSuccess) {
             NSLog(@"Err");
         }
         CFArrayAppendValue(arrayContent, (const void *) keychain);
    }
    
    NSArray *allIdentities = NULL;
    
    NSDictionary *query = @{(id)kSecMatchSearchList:(id)CFBridgingRelease(arrayContent),
                            (id)kSecClass:(id)kSecClassIdentity,
                            (id)kSecReturnRef:(id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                            (id)kSecMatchLimit:(id)kSecMatchLimitAll};
    
    status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&allIdentities);
```

Unfortunately, in the last line, it fails on the following error :

```
Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFTypeRef *' (aka 'const void **') is disallowed with ARC
```

I can, of course, disable ARC for the file contain this method... but I wonder if there's a better approach to make it compile with minimal usage of CoreFoundation objects.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you considered introducing an intermediate `CFTypeRef` variable that `SecItemCopyMatching` can write to, then casting that result to the type you need after checking `status`? e.g., `CFTypeRef queryResult = NULL; status = SecItemCopyMatching(..., &queryResult); if (CFGetTypeID(queryResult) == CFArrayGetTypeID()) { /* cast to NSArray and process */ }`